# Python - TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Tags: python

Have got the following code so far:

```
class beam(object):

    def __init__(self, E, I, L):
         self.E = E  
         self.I = I  
         self.L = L  
         self.Loads = [(0.0, 0.0)] #[(Force, distance along beam)]

    def getTotalDeflection(self, x):
        """Calculate total deflection of beam due to multiple loads"""
        loadsList = self.Loads
        beam.beamDeflection(loadsList, x)

    def getSlope(self, x):
        """Calculate gradient at a point x on beam due to deflection
        """
        import scipy.misc
        return scipy.misc.derivative(self.getTotalDeflection(x), x)
```

For the function getSlope(), I need to calculate the slope by finding the derivative of deflection with respect to x. However, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\X\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\X\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/X/Downloads/beamModel.py", line 12, in <module>
    class beam(object):
  File "C:/Users/X/Downloads/beamModel.py", line 67, in beam
    print b.getSlope(1.0)
  File "C:/Users/X/Downloads/beamModel.py", line 62, in getSlope
    return scipy.misc.derivative(self.getTotalDeflection(x), x)
  File "C:\Users\X\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\common.py", line 258, in derivative
    val += weights[k]*func(x0+(k-ho)*dx,*args)
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't call the function, pass it in to `scipy.misc.derivative`, eg

```
def getSlope(self, x):
    """Calculate gradient at a point x on beam due to deflection
    """
    import scipy.misc
    return scipy.misc.derivative(self.getTotalDeflection, x)
```

Comment: Done but it is giving the same error. Thanks.